# how to pass dynamic lat long values in the javascript function from the angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

i want to show one marker in the google maps. static lat long marker im able to show but im not able to pass dynamic lat long values to the function.

how to pass   {{names.lat}}, {{names.longitude}} to the function. show that i can get dynamic marker.

im using angular js and webapi to get the dynamic coordinates.

response data from rest api[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfv4T.png)

```
{"id":232,"lat":"17.4462","longitude":"78.3823","deviceid":"1","updatedDate":"2018-04-09T14:59:27.76","DeviceTime":null}
```

code

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('ngApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.marker = null;
            $scope.map = null;

            function initMap() {
                $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { zoom: 4 });
            }
            $http.get('url')
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response)
                    $scope.names = response;
                    $scope.marker = new google.maps.Marker(
                        {
                            map: $scope.map,
                            position: new google.maps.LatLng({ $scope.names.lat, $scope.names.longitude }),
                            title: 'Hello World!'
                        }
                    );
                });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="ngApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDci4vYApOxVdKqwlpXSv9h77AcWbNuzmQ&callback=initMap">
    </script>
</body>
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfv4T.png)

Comment: And where are you getting 'dynamic' long lat from ? I don't know what you are asking for here, you have the values you need.

Comment: im getting latitude and longitude from the  $scope.names . lat value comes in  {{names.lat}} and longitude value comes in  {{names.longitude}}. that values i need to assign to MyLatLong of InitMap function

Comment: Just a small edit. Try it and let me know. You are still not defining 'myLatLng' though.

Comment: still i'm facing the myLatLng undefined error. i don't know how to assign the variable to position field. can u update my code

Comment: can you `console.log(response.data)`

Comment: i have added response in the question. please check the console.log(response). im getting data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use `$watch` inside that function, instead use `$scope variables` for `map` and `markers`

```
var app = angular.module('ngApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.marker = null;
    $scope.map = null;

    function initMap() {
        $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { zoom: 4});

    }

    $http.get('url')
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response)
            $scope.names = response;
            $scope.marker = new google.maps.Marker(
                { map: $scope.map,
                position:new google.maps.LatLng($scope.names.lat, $scope.names.longitude),
                 title: 'Hello World!'
                }
            );
            });

    initMap();
    });
```

Comment: it is a brace mistake, keep it inside controller

Comment: still im getting error, i have updated my complete code . please refer it and check the error.

Comment: please console.log(response)

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined

Comment: where did u console? I added console in answer

Comment: change, `$scope.names = response;`

Comment: still getting error. google is not defined.updated the question. with error screenshot

Comment: seems you are having issue with google map insertion. But u said it was working fine with static values

Comment: no issue with google maps. its issue of initMap function declaration. something is wrong in calling initMap function

Answer (score 0):

You could try this in your controller:

```
$scope.$watch('names', function() {
    marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng($scope.names.lat, $scope.names.lng));
});
```

Comment: i tried but gettin error- ReferenceError: marker is not defined. can u plz check my updated question?

Comment: marker definition...I was assuming you may have it in original code...make sure 'var marker=...' is outside any function in javascript..it will be available then.

Comment: i have modified my question .i have added var marker. can u edit my code to get the latlong marker in the map

Comment: @krishnamohan Try now.

Comment: js?key=AIzaSyDci4vYApOxVdKqwlpXSv9h77AcWbNuzmQ&callback=initMap:42 InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map; and not an instance of StreetViewPanorama

Comment: you need to set center property of map. pls do that.

Answer (score 0):

code for making google map marker using web api and angular js

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style>
        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
    <script 
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDci4vYApOxVdKqwlpXSv9h77AcWbNuzmQ">
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            var app = angular.module('ngApp', []);
            app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.marker = null;
            $scope.map = null;
            $scope.lat = null;
            $scope.longitude = null;
            function initMap() {
                $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { zoom: 14, center: { lat: 17.4462, lng: 78.3823}});
            }
            $http.get('api url')
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response.data.longitude)
                    $scope.names = response.data;
                    $scope.lat = response.data.lat;
                    $scope.longitude = response.data.longitude;
                    $scope.marker = new google.maps.Marker(
                        {
                            map: $scope.map,
                            position: new google.maps.LatLng($scope.lat, $scope.longitude),
                            title: 'Tracker'
                        }
                    );
                });
            initMap();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="ngApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
```